# Python 3.x: finding the biggest number from page navigation section?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, urllib

I am creating a program to fetch the biggest number from the page-navigator bar.I'm very close to completing the program.But because I just started coding for the first time 3 days,I'm not able to find the flaw here.

```
import bs4
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

#List for extended links to the base url
links = ['Link_1/','Link_2/','Link_3/']

#Function to find out the biggest number present in the page navigation 
section.Every element before 'Next→' is consist of the upper limit
def page_no():
 bs = soup(html, "html.parser")
 max_page = bs.find('a',{'class':'next page-numbers'}).findPrevious().text
 print(max_page)

#url loop
for url in links:
 my_urls ='http://www.example.com/category/{}/'.format(url)
 page_no()

# opening up connection,grabbing the page
uClient = uReq(my_urls)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()
```

Errors:
    `Traceback (most recent call last):
     line 20, in <module>   page_no()`

```
line 14, in page_no
bs = soup(html, "html.parser")
NameError: name 'html' is not defined`
```

I tried to create this program without creating a function,but it was just returning me the value of the last element from the list instead of all the numbers.

Confusion:

Confused with the sequence of elements `def page_no()` , `#Url Loop` and `# opening up connection,grabbing the page` (I could be wrong)

Thanks in Advance.

Example of Page Navigator:

`1 2 3 … 15 Next →`

Comment: in the line `bs = soup(html, "html.parser")` the `html` is coming from nowhere, you don't define it before you invoke it, so you're getting the error  `name 'html' is not defined`

Comment: @OferSadan You're right. Voting to close.

Comment: I wouldn't vote to close... it's a legitimate question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to parse the page before you ever grab it.

Move this line

```
page_no()
```

to the end, after you grabbed the page. But even then, you name your "grabbed page" `page_html` but within `page_no()` you are looking for another name, `html`. So you can try to change that too, replace

```
bs = soup(html, "html.parser")
```

with

```
bs = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
```

P.S, you have additional problems like indentation problems in your code, you'll have to sort them out too for this to work

Comment: Thanks for the help,Could you point out the error with the indentation.Since I am not getting the warning for the same & Now the program is running but I am just getting the value from the last element of the list.

Comment: Take a look at the code you pasted, none of it is indented at all... i'm guessing it looks different in your editor if it works, so feel free to ignore that remark

Comment: It was a pasting error,my bad.I have done the indentation now here.But why I am getting the value of the last element only?Can you help me on that as well?

Comment: not without seeing the actual url, but either way, it's the subject of a new question entirely... I suggest you open another question with proper code and the true url you're parsing, and provide the expected output vs. the output you're currently getting